# LINQ continue after Take

Tags: c#, linq

Say we have an `IEnumerable<T> stuff;`

Is there a concise way to Take n elements and then another m elements after the first, without re-evaluating?

example code:

```
stuff.Take(10);
stuff.Skip(10).Take(20); // re-evaluates stuff
```

What I was thinking was maybe this (not working code)

```
var it = stuff.GetEnumerator();
it.Take(10);
it.Take(20);
```

Edit to add to the difficulty and to clarify the complexity of what I would like to accomplish: I want to *continue* the query after the Take, i.e.

```
it.Take(10);
var cont = it.Select(Mutate);
cont.Take(20);
cont = cont.Where(Filter);
cont.Take(5);
```

Comment: You could say that the question you linked is relevant, however those answers are not. Most are variations of "do it yourself" with bad code example.

Comment: `var temp = stuff.Take(30).ToList();` then `var firstTen = temp.Take(10);` and `var nextTwenty = temp.Skip(10).Take(20);`

Comment: If you are having a problem using the answers provided, then explain, in your question, how you're using those answers and how, specifically, it's failing to solve your problem.

Comment: @juharr That's constantly searching through the beginning of the sequence.  You'll end up iterating ~n^2 items doing that.

Comment: @Servy It's actually more like m*n where n is the size of the collection and m is the number of batches.  And in this case m seems to be 2.

Comment: half the people can't even read the question right >_>

Comment: @ManuelSchweigert That likely means the question is poorly written.

Comment: @juharr No, it's not.  For the first batch you're looking at 10 items, then for the second it's 20, then for the third it's 30, and for the fourth it's 40, and so on.  So that means you end up iterating over n^2 items where n is the number of actual items you want to get (not necessarily how many are in the collection itself, if you end up not iterating it completely).

Comment: that method does not solve my problem and is also not concise, I'd write a better one myself.

Comment: @ManuelSchweigert In what way does it not solve your problem?  If you'd rather write your own than use one provided by someone else, then that's fine, write your own, and don't ask others for how they'd write it.  You could even post your solution as an answer to the canonical question, if you feel that it's better than all of the existing solutions.

Comment: @Servy I must be missing something as I didn't see anything about a 3rd batch of 30 just the first 10 then the next twenty,  Maybe the questions has been editted and I missed that,

Comment: @juharr I must be missing something as I didn't see anything about a restriction that it would never ever ask for more than a second batch; I only saw it asking for how to get the next batch from any given batch.  Maybe the question has been edited and I missed that.

Comment: @Servy I appended to the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just create a wrapper for `IEnumerable` that will handle any LINQ appended on and take one pass through the source, use this class and extension:

```
public static class EnumerableOnceExt {
    public static EnumerableOnce<IEnumerable<T>, T> EnumerableOnce<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src) => new EnumerableOnce<IEnumerable<T>, T>(src);
}

public class EnumerableOnce<T, V> : IEnumerable<V>, IDisposable where T : IEnumerable<V> {
    EnumeratorOnce<V> onceEnum;

    public EnumerableOnce(T src) {
        onceEnum = new EnumeratorOnce<V>(src.GetEnumerator());
    }

    public IEnumerator<V> GetEnumerator() {
        return onceEnum;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return onceEnum;
    }

    public void DoSkip(int n) {
        while (n > 0 && onceEnum.MoveNext())
        --n;
    }

    public void DoTake(int n) {
        while (n > 0 && onceEnum.MoveNext())
            --n;
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (!disposedValue) {
            if (disposing) {
                onceEnum.ActuallyDispose();
            }

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    #endregion
}

public class EnumeratorOnce<V> : IEnumerator<V> {
    IEnumerator<V> origEnum;

    public EnumeratorOnce(IEnumerator<V> src) {
        origEnum = src;
    }

    public V Current => origEnum.Current;

    object IEnumerator.Current => origEnum.Current;

    public bool MoveNext() => origEnum.MoveNext();

    public void Reset() {
        origEnum.Reset();
    }

    public void ActuallyDispose() {
        origEnum.Dispose();
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        // don't allow disposing early
    }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Now your sample code will work if you call `EnumerableOnce()` to wrap the source, as long as you execute the enumerations:

```
var it1 = it.EnumerableOnce();
it1.Take(10).ToList();
var @continue = it1.Select(Mutate);
@continue.Take(20).ToList();
@continue = @continue.Where(Filter);
@continue.Take(5).ToList();
```

You can also add new methods to `EnumerableOnce`:

```
public void DoSkip(int n) {
    while (n > 0 && srcEnum.MoveNext())
    --n;
}

public void DoTake(int n) {
    while (n > 0 && srcEnum.MoveNext())
        --n;
}
```

And call them:

```
var it1 = it.EnumerableOnce();
it1.DoTake(10);
var @continue = it1.Select(Mutate);
@continue.DoSkip(20);
@continue = @continue.Where(Filter);
@continue.DoTake(5);
```

Comment: I have tried a similar solution first and tried your code again to be sure and it does not yield the desired result:

        var ar = new[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        
  var it = ar.EnumerableOnce();
  
  it.Take(2);
  
  Console.WriteLine(it.First()); // expected output: 2
 output is 0.

Comment: You **must** remember that LINQ operations do not execute unless you do something to cause execution; e.g. `Take()` does not actually take anything, it just creates a condition in a pipeline for restricting results _once they are enumerated_. If you don't do the enumeration, nothing happens, hence the need for either `ToList()` or `DoTake()`.

Comment: I did think that it must be me... :D

Comment: You could create a variation of `EnumerableOnce` that executes e.g. `Take` or `Skip` immediately, but that is not how LINQ is designed and I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: @ManuelSchweigert In your example you did not get the expected result of 2 because `it.Take(2)` is not eagerly evaluated so the first 2 items are never enumerated. If you changed it to `it.Take(2).ToArray()` you would get the expected answer. The `Publish` method in `System.Interactive` (my solution) would behave exactly the same way.

Comment: @JasonBoyd Your answer says `System.Interactive` ?

Comment: yep, it behaved as it should. Well both answers are correct now, but I like this one better for not having to include a library (although I agree that Ix is great).

Comment: @ManuelSchweigert Yeah, I get not wanting to take a dependency for a single function - I wouldn't either. This answer is a good start to avoiding that but it is not complete - there are not-so-obvious edge cases around `IDisposable` that need to be addressed (or that you need to be mindful of). The current implementation publicly exposes the `IEnumerator` that it holds internally which could allow it to be inadvertently disposed of (any number of LINQ methods could do that or even a simple `foreach`).

Comment: @JasonBoyd Very good point - a test with `File.ReadLines` shows the original implementation failing after `foreach`. I have updated the answer with a version that wraps the `IEnumerator` so `Disposable` won't be called, but then you must use use `using` or call `Dispose` manually if you need to ensure the enumerator is disposed of early/properly.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Publish` extension method in the `System.Interactive` NuGet package put out by Microsoft to accomplish this. This is a fantastic library that provides some 'missing' LINQ functions. From the documentation, the `Publish` method:

> Creates a buffer with a view over the source sequence, causing each enumerator to obtain access to the remainder of the sequence from the current index in the buffer.

I.e. it allows you to partially enumerate a sequence and the next time you enumerate the sequence you will pick up where the previous enumeration left off.

```
var publishedSource = stuff.Publish();

var firstTenItems = publishedSource.Take(10).ToArray();
var nextTwentyTransformedItems = publishedSource.Take(20).Select(Mutate).ToArray();
// How you apply 'Where' depends on what you want to achieve.
// This returns the next 5 items that match the filter but if there are less
// than 5 items that match the filter you could end up enumerating the
// entire remainder of the sequence.
var nextFiveFilteredItems = publishedSource.Where(Filter).Take(5).ToArray(); 
// This enumerates _only_ the next 5 items and yields any that match the filter.
var nextOfFiveItemsThatPassFilter = publishedSource.Take(5).Where(Filter).ToArray()
```

Comment: um, is `source` supposed to be `publishedSource`?

Comment: looks like what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @ManuelSchweigert If you don't actually need to continue evaluating a query after calling a `Take`, and are actually okay just repeatedly iterating the entirety of the query up until that point to continue getting items, then you should adjust the question accordingly, otherwise you're going to get people looking for an answer to the question asked, and not finding answers to that question.  If you just want to know how to cache the results of a query into a data source then you should ask that question instead.

Comment: @Servy I need neither of the things you are talking about. This answer is perfectly fine for my question...

Comment: @ManuelSchweigert Well the things that you claim you don't need are precisely what this answer is providing, so if that's not what you want, then this answer isn't giving you what you want.  If the answer *is* what you want, then you should amend your question so that you're not asking for things that you don't need, and not asking for things that you do need.

Comment: @Servy I think you misunderstand this solution. This does not repeatedly iterate over the sequence, calling `Publish` prevents that from happening.